# Learning Map / Syllabus Visualization

Tags: d3.js, visualization

I have a learning roadmap / syllabus with topics organized around ket areas / domains. I would want to provide an interactive visualization for this learning roadmap using D3.js or comparable. Looking for pointers on similar attempts that I can leverage or get inspired from.

Comment: Maybe a [collapsible tree](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the D3 examples.

These two below look like good candidates for representing the content of a syllabus.

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/pack-hierarchy.html

[image]

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html

[image]

I'm trying to do the same for my class.
Will attempt to use the ones above.

In the pack-hierarchy one, it is nice that it is zoomable.

While in the force-collapsible one, it is nice to be able to collapse subjects.

Somehow a graph representation, might be better than a hierarchy for a syllabus...

Luis